# Sql Model Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This appears mensagem: Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion

my model

```
public function get_parcelasvencidas ()  {
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM parcelas, aluguel WHERE id_aquiler_parcelas = id_alug");
return $query->result();}
```

Comment: What did you get when executed this query in mysql console?

Comment: $this->sindico->get_parcelasvencidas()

Comment: I mean the query result you  executed this query in mysql client.

Comment: you did not see that the problem is in the model

Comment: What do you do in your controller ? Your question is have minimum description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your query is seems wrong. Change with this :

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM parcelas, aluguel WHERE id_aquiler_parcelas = 'id_alug'");
```

Because `id_alug` is value, not variable.

Second, you get an error like this :

> Message: Array to string conversion

Because your return type in model is an object. To get the result use `foreach` instead, like this :

```
foreach($this->my_model->get_parcelasvencidas() as $row)
{
    echo $row->id;
    echo $row->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one little change is,

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM parcelas, aluguel WHERE id_aquiler_parcelas = 'id_alug'");
```